# How to simplify if ( ! in_array( $x, $a ) ) $a[] = $x; in php?

Tags: php, conditional-statements, simplify

I would like to write something like

```
array_unique( $a[] = $x )
```

but it throws me a notice:

```
array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given.
```

Is there a way how to avoid writing

```
if ( ! in_array( $x, $a ) ) $a[] = $x;
```

?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `array_unique` doesn't add elements to an array, it removes duplicate values.

Comment: No, you can't really simplify this. If you only want to add to the array when the new entry does not exist in the array, at some place, hidden or obvious, you'll have to have a test.

Comment: I suppose you're trying to emulate something like `set()` in Python: a collection which automatically deduplicates data as you add it...?

Comment: I don't really see the point, but if you use the value as the key as well, you can simplify it even more. For numeric / string values at least: `$a[$x] = $x;` would not have any duplicate values. Probably more memory usage versus less characters in your code though...

Comment: **jeroem** this is pretty good. Unfortunately I don't have key indexed array. It comes from form. Thanks. It seems it is not possible. Array_unique is not able to evaluate expression in the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches.

Add them and then remove duplicates.

Or use array search (just because it's not in_array as you ask) to check first if the array already contains a value.

```
<?php

$array = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
$array[] = 'foo';
$array[] = 'bat';
$array = array_unique($array); // Remove duplicates
var_dump($array);
$array = array_values($array); // Re-index array if you don't want to preserve keys
var_dump($array);

$array = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
if(false === array_search('foo', $array)) $array[] = 'foo';
if(false === array_search('bat', $array)) $array[] = 'bat';
var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'foo' (length=3)
  1 => string 'bar' (length=3)
  2 => string 'baz' (length=3)
  4 => string 'bat' (length=3)

array (size=4)
  0 => string 'foo' (length=3)
  1 => string 'bar' (length=3)
  2 => string 'baz' (length=3)
  3 => string 'bat' (length=3)

array (size=4)
  0 => string 'foo' (length=3)
  1 => string 'bar' (length=3)
  2 => string 'baz' (length=3)
  3 => string 'bat' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to do is a data structure which automatically deduplicates data as you add it (e.g. `set()` in Python). PHP doesn't have something like that by default.

Two approaches:

1. Use the unique id of an item as key:

   ```
   $a[$x['id']] = $x;
   ```

   This gives you automatic deduplication, obviously.
2. Implement something like `set()` as a class:

   ```
   class Set implements ArrayAccess {

       protected $data = [];

       public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
           if (is_null($offset)) {
               $this->data[] = $value;
           } else {
               $this->data[$offset] = $value;
           }
           $this->data = array_unique($this->data);
       }

       public function offsetExists($offset) {
           return isset($this->data[$offset]);
       }

       public function offsetUnset($offset) {
           unset($this->data[$offset]);
       }

       public function offsetGet($offset) {
           return isset($this->data[$offset]) ? $this->data[$offset] : null;
       }

   }

   $a = new Set()
   $a[] = 'foo';
   $a[] = 'foo'; // deduplicated
   ```

Comment: Who comes first with $a[$x] = $x;? You or Jeroen?

Comment: Rasmus Lerdorf probably. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your function :)

```
function my_array_unique($a, $val) {
    $a[] = $val;
    return array_unique($a);
}
```

Comment: Where does $x come from?